# Error:could not find the gradle wrapper within the android sdk

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm new to Cordova application, I'm trying to run my first Cordova application in visual studio 2015. I'm getting this error please anyone helps me to resolve.

Error I'm getting is
[image]
I attached my Environment Variable Override Image.

[image: This is my Environment variable Override]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of research, i found a solution by replacing wrapper folder from a .gradle file I found this file in C:\Users\.gradle\wrapper to your android_sdk wrapper file. example: D:\android-sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper.